# Как сделать такое меню?

Tags: ajax, html, javascript, css

Нужно, чтобы при клике на меню снизу выпадало его содержание. Например, как у  `htmlbook.ru` только, чтобы выпадал div элемент, в который можно класть дургие элементы.
P.S Это скорее не меню а что то подобное.

К примеру, само меню ul,li а при клике на него все содержимое в div покажет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Откройте для себя [JqueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)

Comment: Спасибо,но не вариант ))

Comment: Вот +1 тебе за это,я про него вообще не знал)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было сделать именно такой [Вот он пример](http://spyrestudios.com/demos/stylish-slider/#)